# Python3: Getting Win error 193 when importing openpyxl

Tags: python

I have a 64 bit operating system with 64 bit python3 installed. When i tried to import openpyxl i got this error:

`import openpyxl`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\FOLDERS\Programming stuff\Python scripts\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import openpyxl
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\openpyxl\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from openpyxl.compat.numbers import NUMPY, PANDAS
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\openpyxl\compat\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .numbers import NUMERIC_TYPES
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\openpyxl\compat\numbers.py", line 9, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: @KlausD. done..

Comment: How did you install numpy?

Comment: @KlausD. normally from pip command

Comment: @KlausD. Ok so i just checked the same in pycharm and it worked this time, what could be the cause of this??